# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException while using @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have weird situation.
I tried to create new bean while using the @Configuration an @Bean this way:

```
package com.spring.beans.ParkingCar;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CarMaker
{
    @Bean
    public CarBean createNewCar()
    {
        CarBean carBean=new CarBean();
        return carBean;

    }

}
```

package com.spring.beans.ParkingCar;

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CarBean
{
    private int x = 3;
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CarBean.class);


    public void driveCar()
    {
        logger.debug("I am driving my car" + x);
    }
}
```

and then my test class looks like this:

```
public static void execute()
    {
        try
        {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");


            CarMaker carMaker = (CarMaker) context.getBean("carMaker");
            CarBean carBean = carMaker.createNewCar();
            carBean.driveCar();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            logger.error(e);
        }

    }
```

my applicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"


    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Must for auto wiring 
    <context:annotation-config />
    -->

    <context:component-scan
         base-package="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar">
   </context:component-scan>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="Spring3HelloWorldBean" class="com.spring.aspect.Spring3HelloWorld">
        <property name="myname" value="idan" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="SecurityAspect" class="com.spring.aspect.SecurityAspect">
    </bean>


    <bean id="CalculateStrategyBean" class="com.spring.beans.calculator.CalculateStrategyBean">
        <constructor-arg value="plus" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="CalculatorBean" class="com.spring.beans.calculator.CalculatorBean">
        <constructor-arg ref="CalculateStrategyBean" />
        <constructor-arg ref="CalculateNumbersHolderBean" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="CalculateNumbersHolderBean" class="com.spring.beans.calculator.CalculateNumbersHolderBean">
        <constructor-arg value="10" />
        <constructor-arg value="20" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="lisenceDrive" class="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.LisenceDrive"
        p:carLisenceNum="333" p:isValidateCar="true" />

    <bean id="AmbulancelisenceDrive" class="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.LisenceDrive"
        p:carLisenceNum="999" p:isValidateCar="false" />

    <bean id="TransitlisenceDrive" class="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.LisenceDrive"
        p:carLisenceNum="111" p:isValidateCar="false" />


    <bean id="TransitVechileDetails" class="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.VechileDetails"
        p:modelName="Transit-AS" p:numOfWheels="4" p:year="1992" />


    <!--  Wiring without annotations-->
    <!--

        <bean id="Ambulance"
        class="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.FourWheelsVechile"
        p:modelName="GMC" p:numOfWheels="4" p:year="1997"
        p:lisenceDrive-ref="AmbulancelisenceDrive" /> <bean id="Bike"
        class="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.TwoWheelsVechile" autowire="byName"
        p:modelName="T-BIRD" p:numOfWheels="2" p:year="2012" /> <bean
        id="Transit" class="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.FourWheelsVechile"
        p:lisenceDrive-ref="TransitlisenceDrive" autowire="constructor">
    -->


    <bean id="Ambulance" class="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.FourWheelsVechile"
        p:modelName="GMC" p:numOfWheels="4" p:year="1997" p:lisenceDrive-ref="AmbulancelisenceDrive" />

    <!--  Wiring with annotations

    <bean id="Bike" class="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.TwoWheelsVechile"
        autowire="byName" p:modelName="T-BIRD" p:numOfWheels="2" p:year="2012" />



    <bean id="Transit" class="com.spring.beans.ParkingCar.FourWheelsVechile"
        p:lisenceDrive-ref="TransitlisenceDrive">
    </bean>
    -->

</beans>
```

Now when I ran it on  MyEclipse thru main it worked just fine. but when I uploaded it to my stand alone application which is running on Linux I got:

```
2012-07-01 14:11:21,152 com.spring.test.Spring3HelloWorldTest [ERROR] org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'carMaker' is defined
```

Any idea why it didn't work there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`@Configuration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) indicates that a class declares one or more [`@Bean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html) methods while `@Bean` creates a new bean which have same name as the name of the method annotated with `@Bean` .
In your code sample bean with name `createNewCar` will be created as method `createNewCar()` method is annotated by `@Bean`.

Try this

```
CarBean carBean = (CarBean) context.getBean("createNewCar");
carBean.driveCar();
```

Few things to look at

1. Why to annotate class `CarBean` as `@Configuration`? It dont contain any bean defination ie. method with `@Bean` annotation.
2. Why to invoke `createNewCar()` method as it is already annotated with `@Bean`? (Let Spring do its work)

Check this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/spring/spring3/configuration-spring.shtml) it will help you to get familiar with `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotation.

Comment: You have a created a bean of type `CarMaker` and with name `createNewCar` and you are trying to access bean with name `CarMaker` which don't exist.

Comment: Why CarMaker is not exists? it does exists. I have annotated it with @Configuration

Comment: `@Configuration` donot create bean. Check links in my answer.

Comment: So how come it worked fine in MyEclipse? this is from MyEclipse Spring log: 2012-07-01 17:42:53,737 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [DEBUG] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'carMaker'

Comment: @rayman: Check my updated answer and go through mentioned links. You have mixed up few things.

Comment: But it's still weird that in MyEclipse environment it worked. weird.

Comment: Yes only in MyEclipse environment.. I mean if I keep it in the same pattern. btw: is there any way I could reach ya out from here? you got a website or anything? thanks.